# CometD OOrt Configuration with Tomcat not working

Tags: java, tomcat, cometd

I am using CometD with Tomcat. I try to get Oort running, but it seems there are some problems with the notification between 2 OORT nodes.

I tried the static but switched to the MultiCastConfigServlet to be sure that i did not make any stupid config errors.

The web.xml setup is the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometdServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>transports</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.server.transport.JSONTransport</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedTransports</param-name>
        <param-value>JSONTransport</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>timeout</param-name>
        <param-value>10000</param-value>
    </init-param>


    <init-param>
        <param-name>jsonContext</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.server.JacksonJSONContextServer</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>10000</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>long-polling.multiSessionInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>2000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>oort</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.oort.OortMulticastConfigServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>oort.url</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/context/cometd</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>oort.channels</param-name>
        <param-value>/appchannel/**,/seti/**</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Seti</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.oort.SetiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

     <servlet>
    <servlet-name>initializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-  class>com.company.server.bayeux.BayeuxInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

I use seti to associate a user with a session. This association must be syncronized via oort with all oort nodes.

In my opinion the Oort.CometListener cometJoined() should be triggered if a new OOrt node comes into play. But this listener method is never called.

I am not sure if this is a tomcat issue or a program error.